# Pandas: Optimize iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I habve a big dataframe in pandas and want to fill one column based on the values from another column. This column contains of sequences of '0' and '1', and I want to caluclate the ratio of these. So this is my working code, but its really slow so do you have a good idea how to speed this up?

```
t1 = time.time();

phase = df.loc[0]['Phase']
sequence_0 = 0
sequence_1 = 0
sequence = 0
ratio = 0

for val in df.itertuples():
    if val[10] == phase:
        sequence += 1
    else:
        if phase == 0:
            sequence_0 = sequence 
        else:
            sequence_1 = sequence 
            if sequence_0 > 0:
                ratio = ( sequence_0 / (sequence_1 + sequence_0) ) * 100
        sequence = 0
        phase = x

    df.at[i,'Ratio'] = ratio

print("Elapsed: %.2f seconds" % (time.time() - t1))
```

So this takes ~10s for a length of the dataframe of ~850k rows.

Thanks and best regards
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Vectorize the calculation. Something like:

```
df[df['col10'] == phase].mean()
```

Should yield the expected result using the appropriate column names.